# Java Call method with return type and method to be called

Tags: java, methods, call

I have lots of calls against a REST API that i want handled the same way.
Perform call, check if not authenticated. Refresh Token call again or if we hit rate
limit despite rate limit function. Sleep and perform call again.

I would like to wrap this in a function that can be called in the way

```
 ReturnType returnVal=  handleIntegration(ReturnType , functionToBecCalled)
```

How can this be achieved?

For the example below something like

```
CustomersResponse customersReponse = handleIntegration(CustomersResponse , connection.customers.findCustomersResponse())
EmployeesReponse employeesRepsonse = handleIntegration(EmployeeResponse , connection.employees.findEmployeesResponse())
```

//Current Code

```
            bucket.consume();
            CustomersResponse customersResponse = null;
            try {
                 customersResponse = connection.customers.findCustomersResponse();
            } catch (IntegrationException e) {
                if (e.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                    this.newAccessFromRefreshToken();
                    customersResponse = connection.customers.findCustomersResponse();
                }else if (e.getStatusCode() == 429){
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    customersResponse = connection.customers.findCustomersResponse();
                }else
                    throw e;
            }   

        bucket.consume();
            EmployeeResponse employeeResponse = null;
            try {
                 employeeResponse = connection.employees.findEmployeesResponse();
            } catch (IntegrationException e) {
                if (e.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                    this.newAccessFromRefreshToken();
                    employeeResponse = connection.employees.findEmployeesResponse();
                }else if (e.getStatusCode() == 429){
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    employeeResponse = connection.employees.findEmployeesResponse();
                }else
                    throw e;
            }
```

Comment: bucket.consume(); does this means you are already using some queue mechanism in your project?

Comment: Yes this is just for Rate Limiter. It will check that calls are not made too often . But we have seen that the API we are calling is not stable and can sometimes givé a 429 although rate limit is not surpassed . But this is just a side note not important for the functionality i want to achiev by the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are at least on Java 8 with lambdas, you can do it like this:

```java
<T> T handleIntegration(Supplier<T> method) {
  bucket.consume(); // I don't know how this fits - BEWARE!
  T response = null;
  try {
    response = method.get();
  } catch (IntegrationException e) {
    if (e.getStatusCode() == 401) {
      this.newAccessFromRefreshToken();
      response = method.get();
    } else if (e.getStatusCode() == 429){
      Thread.sleep(500);
      response = method.get();
    } else
      throw e;
    }
  }
  // I don't know what you want to do with the response, returning it here for example
  return response;
}
```

And use it e.g. as:

```java
CustomersResponse customersReponse = handleIntegration(
  CustomersResponse.class,
  () -> connection.customers.findCustomersResponse()
);
```

Caveat: I assumed `IntegrationException` is an *unchecked* exception. If it is checked or in any case, e.g. `connection.customers.findCustomersResponse()` throws a checked exception, the provided `java.util.function.Supplier` will not do. You will have to provide a functional interface that throws the specific checked exception.

Unrelated Note: `Thread.sleep()` is easy, but you may want to consider a better way, because `sleep` blocks the thread.

Comment: Yes the IntegrationException needs to be handled in some way.  It is not thrown by method.get()

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following with the help of Java 8+ Functional Interfaces and Generics:

```java
public <T> T handleIntegration(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    bucket.consume();
    T result = null;
    try {
        result = supplier.get();
    } catch (IntegrationException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode() == 401) {
            this.newAccessFromRefreshToken();
            result = supplier.get();
        } else if (e.getStatusCode() == 429) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            result = supplier.get();
        } else
            throw e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you could call the method like this:

`CustomersResponse returnVal = handleIntegration(connection.customers::findCustomersResponse)`